# How to protect folder containing a git history

Tags: git, backup

I'm using git to keep track of writing projects and other personal work on my own PC (running a version of Ubuntu).

Although my work is being version controlled, I am worried I might one day lose the whole folder (containing its .git file and the work itself) to mishap or technical failure.

What is the best way to protect or back up the work? (Aside from copying the whole folder to another drive.)

Comment: Well... use gitHub or any other git repository provider ? any solution in the cloud actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily back up your work using Git itself.

I might propose three ways to do that:

- Periodically back up your repository to a pen drive:

  - Plug a flash drive to your PC;
  - `git init --bare` a repository on it;
  - Add it as a named remote in your main repository:

    ```
    git remote add --mirror=push pendrive /media/that_drive_id
    ```

    That `--mirror=push` command-line option will ensure that a simple call to `git push pendrive` will suffice to push *everything* pushable.
  - Back up your repository there using something like

    ```
    git push pendrive
    ```
  - Unmount the drive.

  The next time you will be about to back up, plug the drive then do

  ```
   git push pendrive
  ```
- Another option is to use the `git-bundle` command which might be used to export the whole repository (with history) to a single file which can then be copied off to an external storage.

  This approach looks superficially simpler than the former but its simplicity comes at a cost:

  - No incremental backups: while `git-bundle` can be used to export only specific parts of the history, you must keep what was backed up the last time somewhere, and this is obviously inconvenient and error prone.
  - If the repository grows big, each "bundling" will create a big file.
- Unless your stuff is really private (like passwords) buy private hosting plan from a Git provider and mirror your repository there.

  Mirroring is set up exactly in the same way as for the pendrive approach, just the Git URL will obviously be different.

I personally like the pendrive approach best.